# Docker build using volumes at build time

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to use external volumes during the docker image build ?

I have a situation where I would like to use a configuration inside a external volume during the docker image build time. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you please explain you situation ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(edited to reflect current Docker CLI behavior)

If by 'docker image build' you mean running a single 'docker build ...' command: no, there is no way to do that (at least, not in the most recent documentation that I have read). However, nothing prevents you from performing the step that needs the external volume using direct docker commands and then commit the container and tag it just as 'docker build' would. Assuming this is the last step in your build, put all other commands (that don't need the volume) into a Dockerfile and then do this:

```
tmp_img=`docker build .`
tmp_container=`docker run -d -v $my_ext_volume:$my_mount_path --entrypoint=(your volume-dependent build command here) $tmp_img`
docker wait "$tmp_container"
docker commit "$tmp_container" my_repo/image_tag:latest
docker rm "$tmp_container"
```

This does the same as having a RUN command in the Dockerfile, but with the added volume mount. The `commit` command in the example also tags the image.

It is a bit more complex if you need to have other Dockerfile commands after the volume-dependent one, but in most cases you can combine run commands and re-arrange your install in a way that leaves the manual run-with-volume command last, to keep things simple.

Comment: Hi, I tried your method, and it almost works, except I got tmp_container variable empty. What am I doing wrong and how can I get container ID?

Comment: @Eldhenn, I fixed the commands, now they work with current Docker versions: changed run to use -d option and added wait command.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using quotes around `$tmp_container` two times, but not in the `docker commit` command?

Comment: @florisla: no particular reason. Likely due to sloppy copy/paste from test code. Edited the post to unify the style and have quotes on all commands.

Answer (score 3):

[podman](https://podman.io/) is an alternative to Docker that has an api that is the same BUT also supports mounting volumes at buildtime.

I use this to load data into testdatabases without having to copy the data into the image first.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the file into the docker image (ADD) and rm as one of the last steps

Comment: This isn't really that useful a solution, because while it does prevent the files from being in the final image, the files still become a layer in the build chain and there has to be a full copy, plus all the layer caching & invalidation rules. It's quite heavy, and not quite the answer that I suspect most people are looking for when seeking to mount a volume at build time...

Comment: Yes, I'd probably do it differently today (like add , use and remove the file in the same layer / use it in a builder image) but regarding cache invalidation it will probably still happen if the file changes every build

Comment: Options like `RUN --mount=` absolutely **can** avoid issues with layer invalidation...

Answer (score 2):

We are not restricted to Docker to build OCI images.

With [buildah](https://buildah.io) it's possible to mount volumes from the host that won't be persisted in the final image. Useful for configuration and secrets.

`buildah bud --volume /home/test:/myvol:ro -t imageName .`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADD combined with ARG (build time parameters) to access files or directories during the build without having to hardcode their location.

```
ARG MAVEN_SETTINGS=settings.xml
ADD $MAVEN_SETTINGS ./
```

And now you can change the file location during the build with:

```
docker build --build-arg MAVEN_SETTINGS=someotherfile.xml
```

Comment: I believe that this adds a new layer, which will contain the file, thus making your secrets forever a part of the Docker image until you remove and then squash the image?

Even if you remove the file later in the Docker build, that "remove" instruction will be another layer, on top of the previous one which will still contain the file?