# Why modules are not installed by only binding volume in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I tried `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up -d`

I suffered `api-server` container didn't start.

I tried

`docker logs api-server`

```
yarn run v1.22.5
$ nest start --watch
/bin/sh: nest: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

It seems `nest` packages didn't installed. because `package.json` was not copied to container from host.

But in my opinion,by `volume` was binded by `docker-compose.yml`, Therefore the command `yarn install` should refer to the `- ./api:/src`.

Why do we need to `COPY` files to container ?

Why only the `volume` binding doesn't work well ?

If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

The following is `dockerfile`

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /src

RUN rm -rf /src/node_modules
RUN rm -rf /src/package-lock.json
RUN apk --no-cache add curl



RUN yarn install

CMD yarn start:dev
```

Following is
`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  api-server:
    build: ./api
    links:
      - 'db'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./api:/src
      - ./src/node_modules
    tty: true
    container_name: api-server
```

Comment: Did you add `nest` to `package.json` and then try to rebuild the image?  The contents of the `node_modules` anonymous volume will always take precedence over what was built into the image, and changes to `package.json` will get completely ignored.  You might find a local Node installation more convenient to use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volumes are mounted at runtime, not at build time, therefore in your case, you should copy the `package.json` prior to installing dependencies, and running any command that needs these dependencies.

Some references:

- [Docker build using volumes at build time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086724/docker-build-using-volumes-at-build-time)
- [Can You Mount a Volume While Building Your Docker Image to Cache Dependencies?](https://vsupalov.com/cache-docker-build-dependencies-without-volume-mounting/)